# jQuery multi sliders change slide in one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm using [slidesjs](http://www.slidesjs.com/)  and I want make multi sliders

I have 2 sliders `#show` and `#show2`, and I want that 2 slidersw work in 1 time: slides will be change in one time.

Now now 1 slider slides change earlier than 2, what is wrong in my code ?

I want that slides will  change in one time:

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $("#show").slidesjs({
                width: 900,
                height: 300,
                navigation: false,
                pagination: {active:   false},
                play: {
                    auto: true,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    effect: "fade",
                },
                effect: {
                    slide: {                                                     
                        speed: 200                                                 
                    },
                    fade: {
                        speed: 300,                                               
                        crossfade: true                                
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#show2").slidesjs({
                width: 900,
                height: 300,
                navigation: false,
                pagination: {active:   false},
                play: {
                    auto: true,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    effect: "fade",
                },
                effect: {
                    slide: {                                                     
                        speed: 200                                                 
                    },
                    fade: {
                        speed: 300,                                               
                        crossfade: true                                
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I try `.ready` but slides also change in different time

Comment: @Stano I want sinchronize sliders

Comment: @stano no "pauseOnHover: true" Ii can remove it's not required function, I want syncronize animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them both a class, and target them at the same time.

```
<div class="sliders" id="show"></div>
<div class="sliders" id="show2"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(".sliders").slidesjs({ ... });
```